# Flutter VS Code Emulator stuck at Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, android-gradle-plugin, android-emulator

Since yesterday evening I've been unable to open my app in emulator. It worked fine till then.

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
lib\main.dart:1
√  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
```

It usually takes about 2 mins to open but it was just stuck there for like 15 mins. So I looked up for answers and the first one said to use `gradlew clean` and `gradlew build`. I did that and still was stuck but with another error.

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
lib\main.dart:1
Note: C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\path_provider_android-2.0.12\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\pathprovider\PathProviderPlugin.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
√  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
```

Then I tried an answer from a similar question here that suggested to do `flutter pub cache repair`. Still no luck.

Then I tried another suggestion from an answer here to upgrade flutter. I hadn't upgraded flutter for a couple months since so I did that but still the issue persists.

I read from a comment to a question here that when they run the project using `flutter run -v` in terminal it opened up after about 20 mins. So I started it and because my laptop is like 6 years old running 6th gen i5 with 8gb ram I thought it might take a bit longer. So I left it there and now after about 2 hours my terminal is stuck at:

> I hit the question character limit so I put the terminal's output in
> an online notepad at: https://anotepad.com/notes/3jri4gpc

I just closed the emulator and the terminal added this to the above

```
[+7331895 ms] executing: C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 shell pm list packages com.example.myapp
[  +90 ms] adb.exe: device offline
[  +27 ms] ProcessException: Process exited abnormally:
           adb.exe: device offline
             Command: C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 shell pm list packages com.example.myapp
[   +3 ms] Installing APK.
[  +17 ms] Installing build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk...
[   +8 ms] executing: C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 install -t -r
D:\myapp\front\myapp\build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk
[ +114 ms] Performing Push Install
                    adb: error: failed to get feature set: device 'emulator-5554' not found
[   +6 ms] Installing build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk... (completed in 115ms)
[   +5 ms] Error: ADB exited with exit code -1
[   +4 ms] Performing Push Install
           adb: error: failed to get feature set: device 'emulator-5554' not found
[   +1 ms] Warning: Failed to install APK.
[   +4 ms] Error launching application on Android SDK built for x86.
[   +9 ms] "flutter run" took 7,368,695ms.
[  +23 ms] 
           #0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:10:3)
           #1      RunCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/run.dart:687:9)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #2      FlutterCommand.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:1161:27)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #3      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #4      CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:209:13)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #5      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:281:9)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #6      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #7      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:229:5)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #8      run.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:62:9)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #9      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #10     main (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:94:3)
           <asynchronous suspension>


[ +172 ms] ensureAnalyticsSent: 163ms
[  +10 ms] Running shutdown hooks
[   +2 ms] Shutdown hooks complete
[   +2 ms] exiting with code 1
```

From `[+7331895 ms] executing:`  in the first line after closing the emulator I can see that this was running for about 122 minutes.

I don't understand what's wrong here. Why did the emulator stop working normally all of a sudden?

How to make it work so that I can continue with my app development? Please help.

Comment: try to create new emulator and open it first from android studio if you have and then try to run again

Comment: Did you try with a real device? What's the error in the debug console? Did you try restarting everything?